# XCUITest - Search by label for buttons returns two elements (Button and Static Text)

Tags: ios, nspredicate, xcode11, xcuitest

When I search for a button by label only, NSPredicate used to return only the button so that I can tap on it.
But starting from Xcode 11, NSPredicate returns also the staticText inside it.
Thereby I must update all my tests when I tap a button I must specify explicitly the type (Button).

Anyone have the same issue, know if I should update my tests or it's a known bug ?

Answer (score 0):

This behaviour may be caused by a new simulator version. It is pretty common that UI elements hierarchy trees are different on different OS.

Does this problem appear when you use the same simulator you used with Xcode 10?